# How to set up priority among the shortcodes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am creating a wordpress plugin shortcode. I want this to run after another shortcode from an other plugin has run. So essentially I am looking for some kind of priority among the shortcodes. A quick help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I’m confused by what do you mean by priority. Could you please elaborate with an example?

The plugin will display the related posts etc wherever you put the shortcode.

Comment: As Usman says, the priority is the order in which the shortcodes are included in the editor. If you are looking for some other running order, it doesn't sound like shortcodes are suitable for what you are doing.

Comment: @FluffyKitten and Usman, Thanks for your quick replies. I was under the same expression but my plugin's shortcodes shows the results before the one included on top of it. Do you think there can be any specific way to run the other code first?

Comment: Without seeing the code behind the shortcodes and where they are used, it's impossible for us to know :)  Can you show us what the shortcodes are (e.g. did you write them or are they part of a theme/plugin), how they used, and if you wrote them yourself can you show us the code behind them?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for extending your hand of help. I am astonished why will WP do this specific to my code that it runs one shortcode before other even if it is placed after the other code. Anyhow, I am reviewing it again and will keep you posted.